# Right And Left Side Prompt In Bash

Tags: bash, prompt

I want a prompt on the left side of the terminal and opposite it another prompt on the right side of the terminal...so here is what I have so far and it works partially but the right side of the prompt is on the right but not ALL the way to the right. It's short 23 columns. And I notice that tput cols reports 157 columns total but the prompt will only print characters to the 135th column. Which, again, is 23 columns short of butting up to the right side of the terminal. I counted the number of characters in my right prompt and it's 22.
So here is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

SAVE='\e[s'
RESTORE='\e[u'

COLUMNS=$(tput cols) 

pipe_color='38;2;255;255;255'
pipe_bg_color='48;2;65;74;76'
username_color='38;2;0;0;0'
username_bg_color='48;2;192;197;206'
at_color='38;2;255;255;255'
at_bg_color='48;2;65;74;76'
host_color='38;2;255;255;255'
host_bg_color='48;2;00;91;150'
workingdir_color='38;2;255;255;255'
workingdir_bg_color='48;2;54;128;45'
date_color='38;2;0;0;0'
date_bg_color='48;2;255;167;0'
time_color='38;2;255;167;0'
time_bg_color='48;2;0;0;0'
bar_spaces_bg_color='48;2;167;173;186'
reset_color='00'



function rightPrompt {
printf -v PS1R "\[\e[${pipe_color}m\]\[\e[${pipe_bg_color}m\]|\[\e[${date_color}m\]\[\e[${date_bg_color}m\]%([%F])T\[\e[${pipe_color}m\]\[\e[${pipe_bg_color}m\]|\[\e[${date_color}m\]\[\e[${date_bg_color}m\]%([%H:%M])T\[\e[${pipe_color}m\]\[\e[${pipe_bg_color}m\]|\[\e[${reset_color}m\]"
}

rightPrompt

PS1R_stripped=$(sed "s,\x1b\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z],,g" <<<"$PS1R")


function leftPrompt {
PS1=$(printf "\[\e[${pipe_color}m\e[${pipe_bg_color}m\]|\[\e[${username_color}m\e[${username_bg_color}m\]%b\[\e[${pipe_color}m\e[${pipe_bg_color}m\]|\[\e[${at_color}m\e[${at_bg_color}m\]@\[\e[${pipe_color}m\e[${pipe_bg_color}m\]|\[\e[${host_color}m\e[${host_bg_color}m\]\h\[\e[${pipe_color}m\e[${pipe_bg_color}m\]|\[\e[${reset_color}m\]" '\\u')
}

leftPrompt 

PS1="\[${SAVE}\]\[\e[${COLUMNS:-$(tput cols)}C\]\[\e[${#PS1R_stripped}D\]${PS1R}\[${RESTORE}\]${PS1}"
```